# Extract one column from sql table and insert into another table as multiple records coupled with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract one column from sql table and copy it to another table coupled with multiple values. For example, on the source table I select Col1, and copy over to resulting table with first column auto incremental, second column is the column value copied over from source, and third column will be another numeric value, but we need to create 3 records with values 10,20, and 30 for each copied column value.

Source table:

```
+--------+---------+------+
|  Col1  |  Col2   | Col3 |
+--------+---------+------+
| Value1 | Value10 |  123 |
| Value2 | Value20 |  123 |
| Value3 | Value30 |  123 |
+--------+---------+------+
```

secondary table:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| ColI |  Col1  | ColII |
+------+--------+-------+
|    1 | Value1 |    10 |
|    2 | Value1 |    20 |
|    3 | Value1 |    30 |
|    4 | Value2 |    10 |
|    5 | Value2 |    20 |
|    6 | Value2 |    30 |
+------+--------+-------+
```

What query (MS SQL) to apply on this scenario? The second table is already created with Auto incremental first column, and the multiple values are always (10,20, and 30).

Comment: If your data is well known and repetitive, would there be anything wrong with populating the second table from a script?

Comment: Script should work, I'm trying to minimize the dependency by doing it in TSQL. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:
**[SQLFIddleExample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3ce06/3)**

```
SELECT t1.Col1, t2.COLII
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 10 as COLII
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 20 as COLII
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 30 as COLII) t2
```

Result:

```
|   Col1 | COLII |
|--------|-------|
| Value1 |    10 |
| Value1 |    20 |
| Value1 |    30 |
| Value2 |    10 |
| Value2 |    20 |
| Value2 |    30 |
| Value3 |    30 |
| Value3 |    10 |
| Value3 |    20 |
```